# What's the deal with a bootloader?

Tags: arduino, atmega, bootloader

I am planning to buy an ATmega328 chip from Atmel, place it in my Arduino board, program it, detach it later, then solder onto a PCB.

Can I just buy the chip and program it on the Arduino board, or does it need to have an Arduino bootloader?

Comment: You can use your existing Arduino board as an ISP adapter to program a bootloader and/or application program into your new chip after placing it on your board.

Comment: @user3731004 - what is an "Atmel385"? Atmel don't recognise it, nor do they recognise atmega385, or attiny385. Do you mean [Atmega328](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega328.aspx)?

Comment: @user3731004 - will the chip 'look like an Arduino' in the target PCB ("then solder onto a PCB")? I.e. would it be able to reprogram *itself* over serial I/O *after* it has been soldered into the target PCB?

Comment: If you program (or buy it with) an arduino style bootloader, yes.  Otherwise, no.

Comment: @gbulmer, yes I meant an Atmel328, my apologies

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't "... just buy the chip and program it on the Arduino board"

Unless you buy a pre-programmed ATmega328, you will need an In-Circuit Serial Programmer.

Atmel sell the [AVRISP mkII](http://www.atmel.com/tools/avrispmkii.aspx).
Just for guidance, you might pay over 30 GBP for one of those.

There are lower-cost option based on the Open Source [USBtiny](http://dicks.home.xs4all.nl/avr/usbtiny/)

It has been improved and turned into a kit by [Ladyada](http://www.adafruit.com/products/46)

A friend bought one from a well-known marketplace web site, and it works fine. 
I just did a quick check and found it ready made for under £5 without the plastic case. YMMV

There is also a Ladyada DIY-shield project to turn the [Arduino into a programmer](http://www.adafruit.com/products/462)

There are several projects which are even simpler, e.g. [Mega-ISP](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/MegaISP) using breadboard as the socket to hold the unprogrammed ATmega

I would recommend you *either*

1. put a 2x3pin ISP header onto your new PCB, connect it to the chip
   correctly, so that it can be used to program the chip when its
   on-board; this implies RESET and SPI can be used without causing the
   embedded system to break or misbehave, or
2. don't solder the chip into the board, but use a socket instead, so
   that you can extract it

Then it will be straightforward to reprogram the chip if you find a bug in the code, or need to make a change; both are very common. Otherwise it will be hard to fix it.

*Summary*
If you already have an Arduino and breadboard, then you have everything you need to program an ATmega. You don't need to buy an In-Circuit Serial Programmer (ISP), and you will *not* put the unprogrammed ATmega into the Arduino. However, if you are going to do this a lot, an ISP is a reasonable investment.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

That is, it is possible to program it without the Arduino bootloader, but not through the serial port. Without the bootloader you must use ISP to upload code and data into the flash and EEPROM; once the bootloader is in place it is possible to use the serial connection instead.

Note that fuses and lock bits *cannot* be programmed through the serial port but *only* through ISP, so you'll probably want to invest in a ISP programmer regardless.